# "How do I look?" vs. "What do I look like?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

http://www.myanmar-network.net/m/discussion?id=3423487%3ATopic%3A759759

> The earrings were screwed in. "How do I look?" We said, "Beautiful."

This sentence is from"Dreams do come true" by Jim Bishop. 
In this sentence,I want to know the sentence **"how do I look?"**  is the same in meaning **"what do I look like?.**

Comment: ["He, look-a-like-a-man."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4EH0RtVlgE) The key lies in the details, "you no say details before."

Answer (score 0):

**How do I look** and **What do I look like** do not mean the same thing.

**How do I look** is a question to ask somebody when you are wearing something new (like the earrings from the example you provided). They can answer with something like 'beautifull', 'normal', 'ugly' etcetera.

**What do I look like** is a question of comparison. If you dress up as a cop and ask somebody "what do I look like?". They'll probably answer with "like a cop".